# VBA (Excel): Step Over debug and crash down with application.run

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with VBA Excel.
I have the following function:

Function (...)
...
Application.run "subname"...
...
end Function

**First question:**
While I'm debugging with Step Over (shift F8) at Application.run line, the debugger go to "subname" sub that's it do a Step Into debug (F8 alone) instead of a Step Over (shift F8).

So the question is: is possible to do Step Over debug with Application-run?

**Second question:**
If I stop the macro during the execution of the Application.run command then Excel automatically close!

So the question is: there is an alternative to application.run command?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same problem you mentioned and I tested creating an Application object to do the Run method, which solved the crash.

An example:

```
Function AddSpace(val1) As String
    AddSpace = val1 & " "
End Function

Sub TestRunAnotherFunction()
    Dim result, o
    Set o = Application()
    result = o.Run("AddSpace", "One")
    result = result & "detail"
End Sub
```

But I was not satisfied and wanted to figure out why this was happening in both Excel 2013 and 2016. What I found was if you explicitly set a function to return a **String**, Excel will crash when you either Reset while in that function or an error is thrown in there (provided you do not utilise the Application object methodology above).

Coders more hard-core than me might be able to elaborate more thoroughly on what is happening behind the scenes to cause this. I do not want to speculate further. :-)

Comment: I get the same error when my function is returning a user-defined class (not a string). The above fixed it for me too!